# Backup cell phone text messages to PC for archiving and searching?

Tags: backup, android

I have an Android OS phone and I'd like to somehow archive my SMS messages to a PC or a web service, ultimately so I can search through them. Is there an easy and/or convenient way to do that?

In an ideal world, I'd love it if there was somehow a service that would act as a proxy and automatically archive them online, without any manual process involved. Any ideas?

Comment: Because you're asking about software to interface between your Android handset and your computer, this question _is_ on-topic for Super User. However, it's possible that you'll get a better, more detailed answer on http://android.stackexchange.com/, as that SE site focuses specifically on Android.

Comment: (If you do decide you would rather ask on Android.SE, flag for a moderator and they can move it for you, so you don't have to make a new question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice), then any texts sent to that number would be saved on your google account. You could then search through them, and send and receive SMS from your computer in addition to on your phone. I believe Android has an native client for it so you can send and receive texts and calls with Google Voice from your Android device easily.

Answer (score 1):

[SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) will upload all your SMS/MMS messages to a Gmail account (among other things it does).  Runs as a service on your phone and can automatically upload in the background as messages come in.